# Are SystemColors the same on all versions of Windows?

Tags: c#, wpf, winforms

The .NET framework contains classes which define so called "system colors". For WinForms it's [System.Drawing.SystemColors](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.systemcolors(v=vs.110).aspx) and for WP* it's [System.Windows.SystemColors](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.systemcolors.aspx). I have two questions regarding that:

1. Are the default values of system colors the same on all versions of Windows? If no where can i find the actual values?
2. Are the system colors somehow configurable? Is it possible for the user to globally change the appearance of all applications using `SystemColors`?

If the colors indeed are changeable and I want to maintain the same look of my application regardless of user configuration of colors and OS version i assume i must not use the `SystemColors` and instead create my own colors configuration and use it throughout the code, is that right?

Comment: You will find this post from WPF Team Blog useful: [SystemColors Reference](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/wpf/2010/11/30/systemcolors-reference/)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you take a look at [`KnownColorTable.cs`](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Drawing/commonui/System/Drawing/KnownColorTable.cs) source code, you will see the class gets the color using Windows API [`GetSysColor`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724371(v=vs.85).aspx) function which returns the color based on OS/user configurations.

So here are answers to your questions:

1. No, they are not the same. They are configurations at OS/user level. Each Windows theme specifies the system colors differently.  You can tweak the system colors yourself to create your own Windows theme
2. Yes, you can change them programatically using [`SetSysColors`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724940(v=vs.85).aspx) method. This function changes the color for the current session only. To persist the change, you must update the registry keys at `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Control Panel\Colors`.

**Additional Resources:**

- You will find this post from WPF Team Blog useful: [SystemColors Reference](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/wpf/2010/11/30/systemcolors-reference/)
- [`SetSysColors`](http://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/user32/SetSysColors.html) page in PInvoke.net. The page contains example of setting the color using this method and also using registry.

Answer (score 7):

1) No, the default colors have changed with different versions of Windows. Just compare XP to Win10 and you realize that the coloring is very different.

2) Yes, they are user configurable from "Control Panel\Appearance and Personalization\Personalization".

There is nothing that forces you to use the system colors inside of your app so if you don't refer to them it won't affect anything inside your app. It will however still affect the chrome parts of the window (i.e. border etc.)

Answer (score 2):

System colors are indeed changeable by the user.

For example, on Windows 10 you can choose the "Personalisation" option in Control Panel to modify them.

Therefore, to answer your specific questions

1. There is no such thing as the default value, as Windows ships with multiple themes that are selectable at installation.
2. The colours are configurable, and the user can change them globally.