# System Color palette changed on new Visual Studio 2010 development system

Tags: visual-studio, winforms, color-scheme

I have a new Windows 10 Development system where Windows Forms color palette is different in Visual Studio 2010 from the previous system.

Many of the "System Colors" are now white - example "ButtonFace".

How can I get these colors back to the same values as they were on the old development system?

What changed or corrupted them?

=============== Thanks for Replies ======================

Reza;

Thanks for the suggestion.  I will do that - to 1200 controls on the various application pages.

Arrgh!  One does what one must do.

Andy;

I am supporting a product that has dependencies on third-party controls - which only work when compiled in VS 2010.  It is a monstrous effort to replace them, and the replacements won't be ready for quite a while.

Yes - we will be targeting VS 2019 (or maybe VS 2023).  In the mean time - there is a product with some new feature requests which need to ship right now - and the development systems must be moved to Windows 10. Awkward timing that...

I suppose if the engineering constraints were easy, this job would be done by high-school students.

Comment: well, the software you are using is a decade old -- are there patches that need to be applied? Is it even supported anymore? Have you looked in to Visual Studio 2019 Community Edition? it's free.

Comment: `SyetemColors` belongs to OS and .NET get them by calling [`GetSysColor`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-getsyscolor?redirectedfrom=MSDN&WT.mc_id=DT-MVP-5003235) API.  You don't need to change them, when you assign a SystemColor to a Button, depending to the target OS it will show different colors. If you need a specific color across all target machines independent from OS, don't use SystemColor.

Comment: [Are SystemColors the same on all versions of Windows?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37478392/3110834)

Comment: @Mike, please use comment box to add comment and talk with people. Adding comments to the question, makes it unclear and confusing for future readers :)